# Where to place HTML file for a get request in Drupal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I have a static HTML file that I would like to fetch with jquery get request to populate a modal. That way on a page that I want the popup on I can just include a jquery snippet and it will fetch it and render it within a modal on the page.

I have the script set up, but I don't know where to place the HTML file so that it is accessible to my script. It is a standard Drupal install. Would it work to place it in assets and grab it from there? Seems like maybe not... as I've never seen html files within the assets folder in the past (at least seems like bad practice..?)

Comment: Do you have a custom theme, or a custom module? Typically you would put that Javascript in a file inside a module or theme, and then your HTML file would go in there as well.

Comment: In Drupal 8&9 js and css go into Libraray.yml file and folders. How big is the HTML? Few lines, if so put it inside js file.  Otherwise, define your problem better and include code snippets

Comment: @BrianWagner Okay that makes sense, right now it is in a custom theme, but actually it probably is better suited to a module since its a popup that theoretically could be installed on multiple sites.  Thanks